# How to install/import correctly Pillow (3) using Python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, 64-bit?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, python-imaging-library

When I'm trying to **import Pillow** as the following:

```
from PIL import Image
```

the Python shell gives me this error message:

**Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1031
    warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
UserWarning: /home/lacipor/.python-eggs is writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a more secure location (set with .set_extraction_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).**

I don't know what to do with this.
Any ideas??

(I haven't found anything about this on the Internet, although I tried very hard! :( )

Thank you for Your help, People!

**Python 3.4
Ubuntu 14.04, 64-bit**

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same system and settings, and was having the same problem. For me, this worked:

1. In File Browser, check the option "View" -> "Show Hidden Files"
2. Navigate to "Home"
3. Right-click the directory .python-eggs and select "Properties"
4. In the "Permissions" tab, set "Access" for "Group" and "Others" to none

I think this error was due to the fact that anyone who had access to the computer could modify the contents of this folder, and therefore could possibly gain access to do some nasty things.

Good luck!